# Векторы как элементы структуры

Tags: vector, struct, c++

Добрый день.

Хочу написать RRT, ну а для начала захотел написать обычное дерево, только чтобы указатели на правый и левый потомок хранились в векторе.

Пишу:

```
#include <iostream>
//#include <GL\freeglut.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std ;

struct Node{

    int value ;
    vector <Node*> Children(2) ;

};

void Push(int info, Node *&tree){

    if(tree == NULL){

        tree = new Node ;
        tree -> value = info ;
        tree -> Children[0] = NULL ;
        tree -> Children[1] = NULL ;

    }

    if(info > tree -> value){

        Push(info, tree -> Children[1]) ;

    }

    if(info < tree -> value){

        Push(info, tree -> Children[0]) ;

    }

}

void Show(Node *&tree){

    if(tree != NULL){
        Show(tree -> Children[0]) ;
        cout << tree -> value << " " ;
        Show(tree -> Children[1]) ;
    }

}

int main(){

    Node *tree = NULL ;
    int x ;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7 ; i++){
        cout << "Put : " ;
        cin >> x ;
        Push(x, tree) ;
        cout << endl ;
    }

    Show(tree) ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Ошибки:

`expected unqualified-id before numeric constant` в структуре.

`invalid types ' unresolved overloaded function type int ' for array subscript` в каждой функции.

Помогите разобраться. В векторах я новичок, поэтому ошибки могут оказаться тривиальными, заранее спасибо за понимание.

**Обновление**

Как я понял: `vector <Node*> Children(2)` - не стоило так делать. Надо было `vector <Node*> Children ;`.

Но теперь как обращаться к потомкам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Первую ошибку Вы уже исправили. Осталось исправить ещё одну.

```
if(tree == NULL){
    tree = new Node ;
    tree -> value = info ;
tree->Children.resize(2); // эта строка добавляет два элемента.
    tree -> Children[0] = NULL ;
    tree -> Children[1] = NULL ;
}
```

А можно и так было сделать:

```
if(tree == NULL){
    tree = new Node ;
    tree -> value = info ;
    tree->Children.push_back(NULL);
    tree->Children.push_back(NULL);
}
```

Правильно ли оно работает - я не знаю.

В этом коде есть ещё хорошая утечка памяти. Объект то создаете, а удалять - забываете.

Comment: Спасибо, вслед за вашим решение придумал другое: в структуру дописать выделение.


struct Node{

 int value ;
 vector <Node*> Children ;

 Node(): Children(2) {}

};